# Can't get Meteor mobile app to run on Android Emulator

Tags: cordova, meteor, android-emulator

I am trying to turn a meteor based website into a meteor mobile app. I believe that I have everything set up correctly but I cannot get the meteor run android to work with the emulator from Android Studio. I am working in Windows 10. I have tried to delete the `.meteor/local/cordova-build` file and it changed the error to this error I keep receiving:

```
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.1.0, but it should have a minimum version of
     2.4.3 to ensure compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for
     convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1, but it should have a minimum version of
         2.3.0 to ensure compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for
         convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.1, but it should have a minimum version of
         4.1.0 to ensure compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for
         convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
%% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.1.4, failed version requirement:
      <6.3.0
%% Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --buildConfig,C:\Users\DMI
   Intern\eportfolio\.meteor\local\cordova-build\build.json,--emulator:
   Error: Command failed: C:\Users\DMI Intern\eportfolio\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run
   --buildConfig C:\Users\DMI Intern\eportfolio\.meteor\local\cordova-build\build.json --emulator --buildConfig
   C:\Users\DMI Intern\eportfolio\.meteor\local\cordova-build\build.json --emulator
   'C:\Users\DMI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)

C:\Users\DMI Intern\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\coffeescript\1.0.17\plugin.compileCoffeescript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
      ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

How do I make it so that app will run in the Android Studio emulator? Is it even possible on windows?